# Twilio Outbound Voice Decisioning

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-functions, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to have twilio make an outbound call to my bank and enter my information to authenticate.

Unfortunately my bank's IVR menu is not static but rather a limited number of paths that can be taken.

Is there a way to use the Record TwiMl verb and then enter the info for that path?

I'm not sure if this is the possible. TIA.

Comment: How practical would it be to automate this? Isn't easier to just call the bank's IVR?

Comment: I'm trying to make hundreds of payments a month so it would save some time.